# Is transparent hugepage support on or off on these CoreOS machines?

Tags: linux-kernel, coreos

I have a number of CoreOS servers that will be running some database workloads that highly recommend Transparent Hugepages be disabled.

However:

```
~$ cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
cat: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled: No such file or directory
```

Sure enough, the path /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage doesn't exist.

But I'm not really convinced it's switched off.

```
~$ cat /proc/meminfo | grep huge
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:     7872512 kB
DirectMap2M:           0 kB
```

Which is saying my hugepagesize is currently 2M.  Although nothing is using a hugepage currently.

and

```
~$ mount | grep huge
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
```

How do I make absolutely sure this feature is disabled?

Comment: Your kernel doesn't appear to even have the feature at all!

Comment: @MichaelHampton - you're right.  I don't think I need to worry about it.  On Bare metal CoreOS it's there actually.  The machines above are Amazon instances, it looks like they have already disabled it.